# how to run the applet on client side using jsp in server side

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, applet

I am working client -server architecture, i need to install one fingerprint device in client side, then i need to run some application in client side using server side to get the fingerprint image from client to server which has taken from the client side.I am planning like, applets are client sides and jsp are at server sides.please help me out.

Comment: No,In jsp file also you can include applet tag ,Right ??

Comment: yes, in jsp file we have to include the applet  but how we include the client side applet in jsp page and get the input from the client side

Comment: After Jsp file compiles on server side and converts in to html and dispatches in browser .right ?? So now its on client.Its just like html file,Who have some server side code in it which executes on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks fine to me, but what is the exact issue that you are facing.

Comment: Actually, I dont KNow how to start and where to start. I am trying to use  UIDAI fingerprint authentication. End user will install the biometric device at their end, we need the run some application which is invoke the device at client side and capture the fingerprint of enduser and perform some operation then again consoles the output whether he is genuine or not. will you please help me out.

Comment: I can help you, but you need to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

From the Applet you need to call a servlet by using some API like Apache HttpClient.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

You can then use the response of the Http call in your client (Applet).